# Compiler dependent error when computing compile-time array

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, compile-time

My goal is to compute array of factorials at compile time without creating any class objects or calling static functions. Here is minimal code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cinttypes>
#include <array>

namespace CompileTime
{
    enum {MaxFactorial = 10};

    template<size_t N, size_t I = N-1>
    class Factorial : public Factorial<N, I-1>
    {
    public:
        static const uint64_t value;
    };


    template<size_t N>
    class Factorial<N,1> : public Factorial<N, 0>
    {
    public:
        static const uint64_t value;
    };

    template<size_t N>
    class Factorial<N,0>
    {
    public:
        static const uint64_t value;
        static std::array<uint64_t,N> array;
    };


    template<size_t N>
    const size_t Factorial<N,1>::value = Factorial<N,0>::array[1] = 1;

    template<size_t N>
    const size_t Factorial<N,0>::value = Factorial<N,0>::array[0] = 1;

    template <size_t N, size_t I>
    const size_t Factorial<N,I>::value = Factorial<N,0>::array[I] =
                                  I * Factorial<N, I-1>::value;

    template <size_t N>
    std::array<uint64_t,N> Factorial<N, 0>::array;

    template class Factorial<MaxFactorial>;

    typedef Factorial<MaxFactorial> PrecomputerFactorial;
}

int main()
{
    using CompileTime::PrecomputerFactorial;

    for(auto x : PrecomputerFactorial::array)
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Compiling with GCC 5.3.0 gives program output:

```
0
1
2
6
24
120
720
5040
40320
362880
```

And with MSVC 2015:

```
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

I have two questions:
First, why `array[0]` has value `0` in both cases, despite being set to `1` here:

```
template<size_t N>
    const size_t Factorial<N,0>::value = Factorial<N,0>::array[0] = 1;
```

Second, why MSVC 2015 fails to compute it?

Comment: Observation which doesn't answer either question: with GCC 6, the factorial is computed and the array initialized at static construction time, _not_ at compile time.  I think you may need to sprinkle some `constexpr`s around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the answer to either of your questions, but I do know how to fix your code so it works in all the compilers I can conveniently test, based on techniques from [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6730362/388520) and [this other old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24280521/stdarray-constructor-inheritance).  I have not tested this with MSVC and am curious to know whether it works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cinttypes>
#include <array>

using std::uint64_t;

// Helper template that computes the factorial of one integer
template<uint64_t I> struct Factorial
{ static constexpr uint64_t value = I * Factorial<I-1>::value; };

template<> struct Factorial<0> { static constexpr uint64_t value = 1; };

// FactorialArray recursively assembles the desired array as a variadic
// template argument pack from a series of invocations of Factorial
template<uint64_t I, uint64_t... Values> struct FactorialArray
  : FactorialArray<I-1, Factorial<I>::value, Values...>
{};

// and in the base case, initializes a std::array with that pack
template<uint64_t... Values> struct FactorialArray<uint64_t(-1), Values...>
  : std::array<uint64_t, sizeof...(Values)>
{
  constexpr FactorialArray()
    : std::array<uint64_t, sizeof...(Values)> ({{Values...}})
  {}
};

int main()
{
  static FactorialArray<10> f;
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < f.size(); i++)
    std::cout << i << "! = " << f[i] << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

I separated computation of the factorial from assembly of the array for conceptual simplicity.  This means that it requires O(N<sup>2</sup>) computation at compile time, unless the compiler is clever enough to memoize `Factorial<I>::value`, which it may well be.

Someone more skilled than I with C++11 features might be able to simplify this, particularly the base case of `FactorialArray`, which is very much cargo-cult + change-things-until-the-compiler-stops-complaining on my part.

`for (auto x : f)` does work with `FactorialArray`; the more complicated loop shown above is to demonstrate that the indices come out right.

Note that `FactorialArray<10, 42> f;` will compile without complaint and will erroneously report that 11! = 42.  In a library for public consumption, it might be worth squirrelling the recursive `FactorialArray` away in a `detail` namespace, then wrapping it in a public template that doesn't take variadic arguments:

```
namespace detail {
    // Factorial and FactorialArray as above
}
template<uint64_t I> struct FactorialArray : detail::FactorialArray<I> {};
```

Exercise for the reader: change this to compute the [two-argument Ackermann–Péter function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function), thus demonstrating both the Turing-completeness of template metaprogramming and how to construct two-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Does the job compiling with both GCC 5.3.0 and MSVC 2015, except not generating `0!`. The right sequence should be `1,1,2...`, but it omits first element (yet I see that `Factorial<0>` is specialized, hmmm)

Comment: I just noticed that myself.  It's a silly mistake -- the base case for `FactorialArray` should be -1, not 0.  Fixed shortly.

Comment: Neat and clear :) But I wonder about one thing - first non-template argument of `FactorialArray` is `uint64_t`, then is it safe to specialize it with `-1` which would be `std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max();`?

Comment: Note the explicit cast added in the most recent revision, without which clang (but not gcc) complains about an "invalid narrowing conversion".  Both the value (`uint64_t(-1) == UINT64_MAX`) and the effect of subtracting 1 from `uint64_t(0)` (arithmetic on unsigned quantities always wraps) are well-defined, though.

Answer (score 3):

A fundamental problem is that you use array subscript operator (`array[0]`) as a constexpr operation. But it is not constexpr until C++17: 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_at

> Why array[0] has value 0 in both cases, despite being set to 1 ... ?

Because the `value` you aim to set to 1 is declared in the base class `Factorial<N,0>` but is hidden by the `value` member in the (base case template) derived class.

By the way, if you do like to calculate factorials compile time with a direct method like this, you'll be able to do this with C++17:

```
template<size_t N>
constexpr auto factorial(){
   if constexpr(N<2){
     return 1;
   }
   return N*factorial<N-1>();
}
```

Comment: It's still not clear to me why `array[0]` and `value` of `Factorial<N,0>` would be not set to '1'. I mean, it's initialized the moment it's defined, right? It's base class member initialization, not derived one, right?