# How to implement bound checking for std::array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, operator-overloading

I have extended the C++ 11 `std::array`, it is working file, but when I try to overload the `operator[]`, I got this error:

```
 error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
 array[0] = 911;
              ^~~
```

Is it possible to implement the `operator[]` adding bound checking for the `std::array` type?

This is the code:

```
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

template <unsigned int array_size, typename array_datatype=long int>
struct Array : public std::array<array_datatype, array_size>
{
  Array()
  {
  }

  // std::array constructor inheritance
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24280521/stdarray-constructor-inheritance
  Array(std::initializer_list< array_datatype > new_values)
  {
    unsigned int data_size = new_values.size();
    unsigned int column_index = 0;
    // std::cout << data_size << std::endl;

    if( data_size == 1 )
    {
      this->clear(*(new_values.begin()));
    }
    else
    {
      assert(data_size == array_size);

      for( auto column : new_values )
      {
        (*this)[column_index] = column;
        column_index++;
      }
    }
  }

  array_datatype operator[](unsigned int line)
  {
    assert(line < array_size);
    assert(line > -1);
    return (*this)[line];
  }

  /**
   * Prints a more beauty version of the array when called on `std::cout<< array << std::end;`
   */
  friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream &output, const Array &array )
  {
    unsigned int column;
    output << "{";

    for( column=0; column < array_size; column++ )
    {
      output << array[column];

      if( column != array_size-1 )
      {
        output << ", ";
      }
    }

    output << "}";
    return output;
  }
}
```

---

Related:

1. [Is it possible to enable array bounds checking in g++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778552/is-it-possible-to-enable-array-bounds-checking-in-g)
2. [Accessing an array out of bounds gives no error, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why)

Comment: Beware of the risks of [inheriting a standard container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034916/is-it-okay-to-inherit-implementation-from-stl-containers-rather-than-delegate).

Comment: You should also watch out for [comparisons between signed and unsigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416414/signed-unsigned-comparisons) such as you with `assert(line > -1);` which will almost certainly fail to pass.

Comment: Reflecting to Francois: Deriving from a POD class (or aggregate classes general) is usually a bad idea and a wrong design. `std::array` is a POD class. No constructors, no assignment methods, no virtual functions, no virtual destructor etc. It may be functional, but it is a dangerous and not recommended design.

Comment: @FERcsI, can you reference something explaining how it is dangerous?

Comment: If you create a new POD class based on the original one, there should be no problem. But since using a POD as a base class is not recommended, theoretically it could lead to undefined behavior. However, if you break this and create constructor, destructor, assignment operator, compiler may behave differently than expected.

Comment: Use dependency injection and wrapper functions instead. Using optimization, the final result (machine code) will be the same. Here, also you have the possibility to hide unnecessary functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the return value of `operator[]` on the left side of an assignment, you have to return the array element by reference, not by value.

You also have a recursive loop, as you are calling your own `operator[]` from inside of itself. You want to call the base class's `operator[]` instead, so you need to qualify it.

Try this:

```
array_datatype& operator[](unsigned int line)
{
    assert(line < array_size);
    assert(line > -1);
    return std::array<array_datatype, array_size>::operator[](line);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
array_datatype& operator[](unsigned int line)&
array_datatype const& operator[](unsigned int line)const&
array_datatype operator[](unsigned int line)&&
```

Comment: This really needs some explanation.

Comment: The third one looks very optional, unless it will bind to something like auto&&

Comment: @lili literal array returned from function call, use `[]` to get element, returning by value is correct.  Handles reference lifetime extension for example.

Answer (score 2):

If you want bound checked access to array elements, just use the `at` method of `std::vector` (or `std::array`) instead of the `[]`  operator.  It is there for that purpose, don't reinvent the wheel :).

See [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/) for documentation of array bounds checking.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution for single dimensional arrays:

```
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

template <unsigned int array_width, typename array_datatype=long int>
struct Array
{
  /**
   * Is it okay to inherit implementation from STL containers, rather than delegate?
   * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034916/is-it-okay-to-inherit-implementation-from-stl-containers-rather-than-delegate
   */
  std::array<array_datatype, array_width> _data;

  /**
   * std::array constructor inheritance
   * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24280521/stdarray-constructor-inheritance
   */
  Array()
  {
  }

  Array(std::initializer_list< array_datatype > new_values)
  {
    unsigned int data_size = new_values.size();
    unsigned int column_index = 0;
    // std::cout << data_size << std::endl;

    if( data_size == 1 )
    {
      this->clear(*(new_values.begin()));
    }
    else
    {
      assert(data_size == array_width);

      for( auto column : new_values )
      {
        this->_data[column_index] = column;
        column_index++;
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Overloads the `[]` array access operator, allowing you to access this class objects as the
   * where usual `C` arrays.
   *
   * How to implement bound checking for std::array?
   * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49419089/how-to-implement-bound-checking-for-stdarray
   *
   * @param  line the current line you want to access
   * @return      a pointer to the current line
   */
  array_datatype operator[](unsigned int line)&&
  {
    assert(line < array_width);
    assert(line >= 0);
    return this->_data[line];
  }

  array_datatype const& operator[](unsigned int line)const&
  {
    assert(line < array_width);
    assert(line >= 0);
    return this->_data[line];
  }

  array_datatype& operator[](unsigned int line)&
  {
    assert(line < array_width);
    assert(line >= 0);
    return this->_data[line];
  }

  void clear(array_datatype initial = 0)
  {
    unsigned int column_index = 0;

    for( ; column_index < array_width; column_index++ )
    {
      this->_data[column_index] = initial;
    }
  }

  /**
   * The Array<> type includes the Matrix<> type, because you can multiply a `Array` by an `Matrix`,
   * but not a vice-versa.
   */
  void multiply(Array< array_width, Array< array_width, array_datatype > > &matrix)
  {
    unsigned int column;
    unsigned int step;

    array_datatype old_array[array_width];

    for(column = 0; column < array_width; column++)
    {
      old_array  [column] = this->_data[column];
      this->_data[column] = 0;
    }

    for(column = 0; column < array_width; column++)
    {
      for(step = 0; step < array_width; step++)
      {
        this->_data[column] += old_array[step] * matrix._data[step][column];
      }
    }
    // If you would like to preserve the original value, it can be returned here
    // return old_array;
  }

  /**
   * Prints a more beauty version of the array when called on `std::cout<< array << std::end;`
   */
  friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream &output, const Array &array )
  {
    unsigned int column;
    output << "{";

    for( column=0; column < array_width; column++ )
    {
      output << array._data[column];

      if( column != array_width-1 )
      {
        output << ", ";
      }
    }

    output << "}";
    return output;
  }
};
```

---

And this is a extension for matrix (multi-dimensional):

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

#include "array.h"

/**
 * C++ Matrix Class
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076624/c-matrix-class
 *
 * A proper way to create a matrix in c++
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618511/a-proper-way-to-create-a-matrix-in-c
 *
 * error: incompatible types in assignment of 'long int (*)[4]' to 'long int [4][4]'
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49312484/error-incompatible-types-in-assignment-of-long-int-4-to-long-int
 */
template <unsigned int matrix_width=3, unsigned int matrix_height=3, typename matrix_datatype=long int>
struct Matrix : public Array< matrix_height, Array< matrix_width, matrix_datatype > >
{
  Matrix()
  {
  }

  Matrix(matrix_datatype initial)
  {
    this->clear(initial);
  }

  Matrix(std::initializer_list< std::initializer_list< matrix_datatype > > raw_data)
  {
    // std::cout << raw_data.size() << std::endl;
    assert(raw_data.size() == matrix_height);

    // std::cout << raw_data.begin()->size() << std::endl;
    assert(raw_data.begin()->size() == matrix_width);

    unsigned int line_index = 0;
    unsigned int column_index;

    for( auto line : raw_data )
    {
      column_index = 0;

      for( auto column : line )
      {
        this->_data[line_index][column_index] = column;
        column_index++;
      }

      line_index++;
    }
  }

  void clear(matrix_datatype initial=0)
  {
    unsigned int line;
    unsigned int column;

    for( line=0; line < matrix_height; line++ )
    {
      for( column=0; column < matrix_width; column++ )
      {
        this->_data[line][column] = initial;
      }
    }
  }

  void multiply(Matrix &matrix)
  {
    unsigned int line;
    unsigned int column;
    unsigned int step;
    matrix_datatype old_matrix[matrix_height][matrix_width];

    for(line = 0; line < matrix_height; line++)
    {
      for(column = 0; column < matrix_width; column++)
      {
        old_matrix [line][column] = this->_data[line][column];
        this->_data[line][column] = 0;
      }
    }

    for(line = 0; line < matrix_height; line++)
    {
      for(column = 0; column < matrix_width; column++)
      {
        for(step = 0; step < matrix_width; step++)
        {
          this->_data[line][column] += old_matrix[line][step] * matrix._data[step][column];
        }
        // std::cout << "this->_data[line][column] = " << this->_data[line][column] << std::endl;
      }
    }
    // If you would like to preserve the original value, it can be returned here
    // return old_matrix;
  }

  /**
   * Prints a more beauty version of the matrix when called on `std::cout<< matrix << std::end;`
   */
  friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream &output, const Matrix &matrix )
  {
    unsigned int line;
    unsigned int column;
    output << "{";

    for( line=0; line < matrix_height; line++ )
    {
      output << "{";

      for( column=0; column < matrix_width; column++ )
      {
        output << matrix._data[line][column];

        if( column != matrix_width-1 )
        {
          output << ", ";
        }
      }

      if( line != matrix_height-1 )
      {
        output << "}, ";
      }
      else
      {
        output << "}";
      }
    }

    output << "}";
    return output;
  }
};
```

---

This is a simple test application for it:

```
#include "array.h"
#include "matrix.h"

void array_tests();
void matrix_tests();

/**
 * To build it use:
 *     g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o main
 */
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  array_tests();

  std::cout << std::endl;
  matrix_tests();
}

// struct Matrixx : public Array< 3, Array< 3, int > >
// {
// };

void array_tests()
{
  std::cout << "Array tests" << std::endl;
  Array<3, long int> array;
  array[1] = 99911;

  std::cout << array << std::endl;
  std::cout << array[1] << std::endl;
  std::cout << array[2] << std::endl;

  Array<3> array2 = {0,0,0};
  std::cout << "array2: " << array2 << std::endl;

  Array<3> array3 = {3};
  std::cout << "array3: " << array3 << std::endl;
}

void matrix_tests()
{
  std::cout << "Matrix tests" << std::endl;
  Matrix<3, 3, long int> matrix;
  std::cout << matrix << std::endl;

  matrix[0][0] = 911;
  std::cout << matrix << std::endl;

  std::cout << matrix[0] << std::endl;
  std::cout << matrix[0][0] << std::endl;

  Matrix<3, 3> matrix2{ {0,0,0}, {0,0,0}, {0,0,0} };
  std::cout << matrix2 << std::endl;

  Matrix<3, 3> matrix3 = { 3 };
  std::cout << matrix3 << std::endl;

  Matrix<3, 1, long int> matrix4 = { 4 };
  std::cout << matrix4 << std::endl;
}
```

Running it, you would see this:

```
Array tests
{0, 99911, 0}
99911
0
array2: {0, 0, 0}
array3: {3, 3, 3}

Matrix tests
{{39593264, 0, 1875895727}, {0, 39593264, 0}, {1875566066, 0, -927864272}}
{{911, 0, 1875895727}, {0, 39593264, 0}, {1875566066, 0, -927864272}}
{911, 0, 1875895727}
911
{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
{{3, 3, 3}, {3, 3, 3}, {3, 3, 3}}
{{4, 4, 4}}
```