# How to add arithmetic operators to std::array?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17, stdarray

I hope to inherit all the methods including constructors of std::array. I try

```
template<class T, size_t N>
class Vec : public array<T, N>
{
public:
    using array<T, N>::array;

    Vec operator+(Vec const& rhs) const
    {
        Vec res;
        transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), res.begin(), plus);
        return res;
    }

};
```

But got some compilation errors.

1. 'begin': no matching overloaded function found
2. I cannot do `Vec<int, 2> v{1, 2};` like std arrays even constructors are inherited.

I may misunderstand something. How to solve those errors. Any better ideas to add arithmetic operators on std::array. Thanks!

Comment: [Ahem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray)

Comment: First you have a typo (res should be rhs), Second std::plus is a type, transform expects *an instance of that type*, third you needs to use this-> in front of begin & end (something about two phase lookup i think?). Fourth, what Lightness said. Remove the using array<T,N>::array to fix brace init (I have no clue why but I think it has to do with array not having a user defined ctor?)  ... [I think it works now?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbbf0a804c5e768e)

Comment: Sure would be great if this was a [mcve] so anyone wanting to copy/paste it didn't need to supply all the rest.

Comment: Be careful of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034916/is-it-okay-to-inherit-implementation-from-stl-containers-rather-than-delegate I don't think it applies yet, but I always do has-a container rather than is-a container, just in case someone tries to extend the class.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, hold on, the reason is complicated, but fear not, the solution is simple. Read on.

`array` is a template so the members of the class `array<T, N>` aren't known before the template instantiation (remember a template can be specialized). And because `begin` appears to be non-dependent on any template parameters its name is resolved at the first phase lookup, before the instantiation of `array<T, N>`, i.e. before the members of `array<T, N>` are known. That's why you get `begin` not found or similar error.

The simple solution is to use `this->begin`. This way `begin` will be resolved at the second phase lookup (after `std::array<T, N>` is instantiated) because now it is clear that `begin` can be a member of the inherited template class.

Also, `plus` should be `plus<>{}` or `plus{}` in C++17.

And a recommendation: try to avoid `using namespace std` [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

[Two phase lookup - explanation needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767626/two-phase-lookup-explanation-needed)

Comment: Thanks, I am still wondering why cannot use aggregate initialization `Vec<int, 2> v{1, 2};`. I am using VS2017.

Comment: I am using namespace std in my namespace. Not sure if it is okay or still bad practice.

Comment: @user1899020 because `Vec` is not an aggregate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24280521/stdarray-constructor-inheritance On the topic of using namespace std, templates still have to be in a header, right? Therefore this isn't restricted to your compilation unit. You're forcing everyone who uses this to put all of std in their namespace. Or you could write "std::" a few times, which seems a reasonable burden.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only add arithmetic operations for std::array, I don't think that you need to create a class for this purpose. You can just define nonmember template operators that will work without direct access to std::array implementation.

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
auto operator+(const array<T, N>& ob1, const array<T, N>& ob2)->array<T, N> {
    array<T, N> res;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        res[i] = ob1[i] + ob2[i];
    return res; 
}
```

And so on for other arithmetic operations.

Comment: or simply use [`std::valarray`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray), no need to create a new class